# Basic read/write clarification in C

Tags: c, input, buffer, output

I'm trying to understand how to read and write in C. Would this store entries from the binary file into the buffer until the end of file.

```
unsigned char *buffer = (char*) malloc (sizeof(char) * SIZE);
FILE *file = fopen(FILEPATH, "rb");
if(file == NULL){
    //error
} else {
    while(!feof(file)){
        fread(&buffer, SIZE*sizeof(char), 1, file);
        // Print out buffer (should be different everytime assume I have different numbers in the file)
    }
}
```

Or would I have to use fseek somewhere there?

Vice-versa to write something to a document would this work? Thanks

```
unsigned char *buffer = (char*) malloc (sizeof(char) * SIZE);
FILE *file = fopen(FILEPATH, "wb");
for(int i=0; i<SIZE; i++){
    // put something into buffer based on i
    fwrite(&buffer, SIZE*sizeof(char), 1, file);
}
```

Comment: You probably should remove the `SIZE*sizeof(char)` and use only `sizeof(char)`, as you are reading/writing `SIZE` number of characters from/to the file.

Comment: Yea I just noticed that as well and changed it

Comment: 1) `sizeof(char)` is 1 by definition. 2) don't use `feof()` this way, use the return value from read/write instead. 3) don't cast the result from `malloc()` it is not needed and potentially dangerous.

Answer (score 3):

No, that would probably crash. :)

1. You're taking the address of `buffer`, which is already a pointer: this is wrong. Just pass `buffer` directly to `fread()`. The value of `buffer` and `&buffer` are only the same when `buffer` is an array; not when it's allocated on the heap like your is.
2. Don't use `feof()`, rely on the return value of `fread()`.
3. [Don't cast the return value of `malloc()` in C](https://stackoverflow.com/a/605858/28169).
4. Don't scale allocations by `sizeof (char)`, that's always 1 so it adds nothing.

Comment: Could you expand on how to use the return value to determine if it is the end of file?

Comment: Lets say the size was 12 bytes, and I wanted to read it 1 byte at a time (which I think my code is doing). Every time it loops would fread return 1? and would fread keep progressing through the file and keep track of that? Would I have to put some counter?

Comment: @joop I've been messing with `read()` and `write()` too much :p I couldn't edit my comment anymore, so I deleted it.